# How to type out and html format a paragraph to send in python email bot?

Tags: python, html, email, smtp, html-email

Here is my mass email bot code that send out an email to multiple emails at once. Im having trouble with the msg part. I want to be able to send a email that has multiple paragraphs with breaks and links with special characters.

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
import pandas.io.formats.excel

e = pd.read_excel("EMAILS.xlsx")
emails = e['EMAILS'].values

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
server.starttls()
server.login("cameronalanofficial@gmail.com", "password")
msg = "hello this is a test"
subject = "test 3"
body = "Subject: {}\n\n{}".format(subject,msg)
for email in emails:
    server.sendmail("cameronalanofficial@gmail.com", email, body)
server.quit()
print("DONE")
```

I want to send something like this:

Hello Person,

My name is blah blah blah this is a big paragraph. My name is blah blah blah this is a big paragraph My name is blah blah blah this is a big paragraph.

This is a link www.soundcloud.com/@45frh!

More paragraphs and info

Another link ww.soundcloud.com/@45frh!

-Sender

I want to keep the return spaces and the format just how it is, however when I try using

msg = """
EMAIL BODY
"""

I keep getting ascii code errors :/